# Unir um dicionario com lista dentro

Tags: python

Tenho que unir dois dicionários com lista dentro, o problema está pq ambos possuem lista dentro.

Codigo:

```
valores = {'valor':[1,2,3], 'valor2':[10,20,30]}
valores2 = {'valor':[4,5,6], 'valor2':[10,20,30]}
unidos = {}

data_atos = {'valor': data_atos['valor'].extend(valores['valor'], 'valor2': data_atos['valor2'].extend(valores['valor2']}
```

Erro:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?

O erro de sintaxe é devido você não fechar o parentese no `extend`, você poder fazer de forma generalista assim:

```
valores = {'valor':[1,2,3], 'valor2':[10,20,30]}
valores2 = {'valor':[4,5,6], 'valor2':[10,20,30]}
union = {}

# Aqui vai percorrer as chaves do dicionario valores
for v in valores:
    union[v] = valores[v]
    union[v].extend(valores2[v]) 

print(union)
# {'valor': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'valor2': [10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30]}
```

Caso você queira uma lista sem repetições, pode usar o `set`, veja como ficaria:

```
valores = {'valor':[1,2,3], 'valor2':[10,20,30]}
valores2 = {'valor':[4,5,6], 'valor2':[10,20,30]}
union = {}

# Aqui vai percorrer as chaves do dicionario valores
for v in valores:
    union[v] = set(valores[v])
    union[v].update(set(valores2[v]))
    union[v] = list(union[v])

print(union)
# {'valor': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'valor2': [20, 10, 30]}
```